# XML results from ExecuteSQL to PutMarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, apache-nifi

I've used the ExecuteSQL processor to run a stored procedure, resulting in a single row with a single column called "xml", which contains the XML generated by the stored procedure. The [PutMarkLogic](https://marklogic.github.io/nifi/nifi-features#putmarklogic-processor) processor expects the content of FlowFiles coming to it to have just the XML. How can I get the FlowFile content into the right form?

The content of the FlowFiles coming from ExecuteSQL looks kind of like this:

```
Objavro.schema�{"type":"record","name":"NiFi_ExecuteSQL_Record","namespace":"any.data","fields":[{"name":"xml","type":["null","string"]}]}avro.codenull:info><es:title>instance</es:title><es:version>1.0.0</es:version></es:info><!-- more XML--></es:envelope>
```

That's what I seen when I direct the `failed` relationship to PutFile (It's writing binary as text, so there are some funky control characters in there). What I'd like to have in the content is just the XML content.

Comment: ExecuteSQL -> CnvertToJson -> ExtractJsonPath. or possible to use script...

Comment: ExecuteSQL -> ConvertAvroToJson -> EvaluateJsonPath -> PutMarkLogic worked. If you'll add your response as an answer, I'll mark it accepted. I'd forgotten that the output of EvaluateJsonPath could go to content, not just to attributes.

Comment: added the answer )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following flow:

```
ExecuteSQL -> ConvertAvroToJson -> EvaluateJsonPath -> PutMarkLogic
```

Don't forget to set `EvaluateJsonPath` output to the content instead of attribute

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `ReplaceText` with a regular expression to remove the non-XML content. If you provide example output and desired "destination" content, I can give you a regex to do it.